# Connection aborted while running the Node.js "hello world" on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, windows-firewall, netstat

## Answered/fixed:

Oops! 10000 points to jimw!

I'm trying to start a hobby project using Node. So I got going:

- installed Node 0.6.14
- copy-pasted the "hello world" program from their homepage in Eclipse
- saved as Main.js
- launched (node Main.js)
- opened http://127.0.0.1/1337
- and then I get this:

  Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1.

Code:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

1. Firebug output:
   Aborted - 127.0.0.1
2. Windows Firewall disabled - same result.
3. Checked netstat:
   netstat -na | findstr 1337:
   TCP    127.0.0.1:1337         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
4. Checked that Node is running - it was.
5. Changed the port - same result.
6. Tried to find Node server logs - can't seem to find any.

Any ideas? Right now I'm kind of baffled that "Hello world" isn't working (!)

Comment: Did you really mean 'opened http://127.0.0.1/1337'? If so, try 'http://127.0.0.1:1337' instead.

Comment: did you really see the log on node.js console?

Comment: Whats the log on the node.js console?

Comment: I did see "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/", that's what was baffling me. I didn't realize that I was just barking at the wrong port :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to close the question, so I'll just answer myself.
jimw's comment was the answer - I was trying to access the wrong port because I entered **localhost/1337** instead of **localhost:1337**, I was just blind.
Thanks a lot ;)